# Можно ли перегрузить оператор класса, используя перегрузку другого оператора? C++

Tags: c++, классы, перегрузка-операторов

Хочу перегрузить оператор `-`(минус) так, что бы перед вычислениями программа определяло большее из чисел. Перегрузил операторы `>` и `<`, но компилятор ругается на попытку вызвать эти операторы в перегрузке.

Возможно ли это вообще?

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    class infinite {
    public:
        infinite() {
            this->maxlen = 30;
            this->arr = new int[maxlen] {};
        //  cout << "конструктор" << &arr << endl;
        }
        infinite(string prototype, int len, int maxlen) {
            this->len = len;
            this->maxlen = maxlen;
            this->arr = new int[maxlen]{};
            int j = len - 1;
            for (int i = maxlen - 1; j<prototype.length(); i--, j--) {
                arr[i] = prototype[j] - '0';
            }
    //      cout << "конструктор" << &arr << endl;
        }
        infinite(const infinite &other) {
            this->maxlen = other.maxlen;
            this->len = other.len;
            this->arr = new int[other.maxlen]{};
            for (int i = other.maxlen - 1; i > other.maxlen - other.len - 1; i--) {
                this->arr[i] = other.arr[i];
            }
    //      cout << "конструктор копирования" << &arr << endl;
        }
        ~infinite() {
            delete[] arr;
    //      cout << "деструктор" << &arr << endl;
        }



        infinite & operator = (const infinite &other) {
            if (this->arr != nullptr) {
                delete[] this->arr;
            }
            this->maxlen = other.maxlen;
            this->len = other.len;
            this->arr = new int[other.maxlen]{};
            for (int i = other.maxlen - 1; i > other.maxlen - other.len - 1; i--) {
                this->arr[i] = other.arr[i];
            }
            return *this;
        }

        bool operator == (const infinite &other) {
            if (this->len == other.len) {
                for (int i = this->maxlen - 1; i > this->maxlen - this->len - 1; i--) {
                    if (this->arr[i] != other.arr[i]) return false;
                }
                    return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }

        bool operator != (const infinite &other) {
            if (this->len == other.len) {
                for (int i = this->maxlen - 1; i > this->maxlen - this->len - 1; i--) {
                    if (this->arr[i] != other.arr[i]) return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            else
                return true;
        }

        bool operator > (const infinite &other) {
            if (this->len > other.len)
                return true;
            else if (this->len == other.len) {
                for (int i = this->maxlen - this->len; i < this->maxlen; i++) {
                    if (this->arr[i] > other.arr[i]) return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            else return false;
        }

        bool operator < (const infinite &other) {
            if (this->len < other.len)
                return true;
            else if (this->len == other.len) {
                for (int i = this->maxlen - this->len; i < this->maxlen; i++) {
                    if (this->arr[i] < other.arr[i]) return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            else return false;
        }

        infinite operator + (const infinite &other) {
            infinite temp;
            if (this->len > other.len) {
                temp.len = this->len;
                temp.maxlen = this->maxlen;
                temp.arr = new int[this->maxlen];
                for (int i = this->maxlen - 1; i > this->maxlen - this->len - 1; i--) {
                    if (this->arr[i] + other.arr[i] > 9) {
                        if (i == this->maxlen - this->len - 1) {
                            len++;
                            arr[i - 1] == 1;
                        }
                        temp.arr[i] = this->arr[i] + other.arr[i] - 10;
                    }
                    else {
                        temp.arr[i] = this->arr[i] + other.arr[i];
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                temp.len = other.len;
                temp.maxlen = other.maxlen;
                temp.arr = new int[other.maxlen];
                for (int i = other.maxlen - 1; i > other.maxlen - other.len - 1; i--) {
                    if (this->arr[i] + other.arr[i] > 9) {
                        if (i == other.maxlen - other.len - 1) {
                            len++;
                            arr[i - 1] == 1;
                        }
                        temp.arr[i] = this->arr[i] + other.arr[i] - 10;
                    }
                    else {
                        temp.arr[i] = this->arr[i] + other.arr[i];
                    }
                }
            }


    //      cout << "сложение" << &arr << endl;
            return temp;
        }

        infinite operator - (const infinite &other) {
            infinite temp;
            if (this > other) {

            }
            else {

            }
        }

        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const infinite &that) {
    //      cout << "вывод" << endl;
            for (int i = that.maxlen - that.len; i < that.maxlen; i++) {
                os << that.arr[i];
            }
            return os;
        }



    private:
        int len;
        int maxlen;
        int *arr;
    };
```

Comment: `if (*this > other)` и у операторов не хватает const квалификаторов

Comment: Спасибо, ошибка очень глупая

Comment: Лучше бы вектор использовать а не реализовывать его функционал....